# Is there a way to simulate a keypress in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript

I've been experimenting with bookmarklet's and need to simulate a keypress. My goal is to mak a bookmark where when you click on it, it clicks every possible combination for a breakout edu. Code should look something like `for (char) in combo { keypress(combo letter) };`

Comment: Why do you need to simulate a keypress? Why not just call the callback function that a keypress would initiate?

Comment: Smart. Didn't think that through